# IOS 7 zooming is not working in a scroll view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I am building a ViewController just to show one image. I added the ImageView programmatically to a scroll view. I would like to allow the user to zoom in and out. This is my code

```
@interface ImageViewerViewController ()<UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *ImageView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *Scroll;

@end

@implementation ImageViewerViewController

-(UIView*) viewForZoomingInScrollView{
    return self.ImageView;
}

-(void) viewDidLoad{
    self.Scroll.minimumZoomScale = 0.2;
    self.Scroll.maximumZoomScale = 1.5;
    self.Scroll.delegate = self;
    NSLog(@"View did load");
    if(self.imageName)
        [self updateImage];
}

-(void)setImageName:(NSString *)imageName{
    NSLog(@"set Image");
    _imageName = imageName;
}

-(void)updateImage{
    self.ImageView =[[UIImageView alloc]init];
    self.ImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.imageName];
    [self.ImageView sizeToFit];
    self.Scroll.contentSize = self.imageName? self.ImageView.image.size: CGSizeZero;
    [self.Scroll addSubview:self.ImageView];
}

@end
```

As you see, I already set the delegate of the scroll to `self` and I added the protocol header and the needed message.

But the zooming feature is not working.

Could you help me please?
I appreciate your time and efforts.

Regards,

Comment: where did you write code to zoom ImageView. Can you share?

Comment: @SuryakantSharma I already shared it. `viewForZoomingInScrollView` message

Comment: I don't see any code to zoom any view.

Comment: Zooming only is not working? are you getting image properly?

Comment: @Anil yes I am getting it properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work as I created a demo of it. If anything do else let me know.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
  float minimumScale = [_floorPlanImageView frame].size.width /[_floorPlanScrollView frame].size.width;
  _floorPlanScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5;  //Change as per you need
  _floorPlanScrollView.minimumZoomScale = minimumScale;  //Change as you need
  _floorPlanScrollView.zoomScale = minimumScale;
  _floorPlanScrollView.delegate =self;
  _floorPlanScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
   return _floorPlanImageView;
}
```

Comment: what is that code please? it seems it is exactly my code and you changed the variable names. right? Dear, I would prefer a correction of my code. I already tried to solve my problem so please tell me what have I made wrong, I don't need a new code from scratch. really thanks

Comment: Surely , you need to change in you - (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView method as your's is different and not passsing the scrollview. I guess that would be all. Rest you could check your connections as its all same and working for me.

Comment: Also make property to be strong and not weak.

Comment: Dear, yes that is. I just added the scrol view ad a parameter and it works. really thanks, please correct your answer and I am going to accept it. Regards

Comment: you the one that I am thankful to. you helped me and I appreciate that. Best regards,